# SQL Select a single category for each distinct id

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, duplicates

I have a table that look like this:

```
id  category
1   motor
1   car
1   truck
2   home
2   garden
2   lawn
3   computer
3   electrical
```

It can be recreated using this SQL:

```
create table categories
(
    id int,
    category varchar(20)
)


insert into categories values(1,'motor')
insert into categories values(1,'car')
insert into categories values(1,'truck')
insert into categories values(2,'home')
insert into categories values(2,'garden')
insert into categories values(2,'lawn')
insert into categories values(3,'computer')
insert into categories values(3,'electrical')

select * from categories
```

Each id has multiple categories to it, I want to select just one category for each id. Lets say just the first one. So I want the final table to look something like this:

```
id  category
1   motor
2   home
3   computer
```

The only way I can think of is through some kind of a loop.

Any suggestions? 
Thanks

Comment: does this have similar answer for MySQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `row_number()`:

```
select c.id, c.category
from (select c.*, row_number() over (partition by id order by id) as seqnum
      from categories c
     ) c
where seqnum = 1;
```

SQL tables represent unordered sets, so there is no concept of a "first" row, unless you have another column that specifies ordering.  You can get a random row by using `newid()`:

```
select c.id, c.category
from (select c.*, row_number() over (partition by id order by checksum(newid())) as seqnum
      from categories c
     ) c
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Having multiple categories on each id is not an advisable design for me.
Each table must have a primary key.

Although you can select unique values by using **DISTINCT**

```
SELECT DISTINCT id FROM categories
```